# How to divide 2 numeric columns in SAS

Tags: sas

Please, how to divide 2 numeric columns in SAS.
For example, the first colum is readmission, the second column is the total_admission, and I need to create a third column called readmission_rate by dividing column A / B

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
readmission_rate = readmission / total_admission ;
```